# Twitter status upload with 140 chars text returning fail response

Tags: android, upload, twitter

When trying to upload a picture to twitter along with text(of 140 char), i am continuously getting twitter text too long response. Has anybody faced the issue? If i update text only (140 char long)with no picture, the status is getting updated successfully.
So what is the text limit for twitter status upload with picture(basically, for statuses/update_with_media api)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the docs for [update_with_media](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/post/statuses/update_with_media):

> The Tweet text will be rewritten to include the media URL(s), which
>   will reduce the number of characters allowed in the Tweet text. If the
>   URL(s) cannot be appended without text truncation, the tweet will be
>   rejected and this method will return an HTTP 403 error.

So, I assume the limit for text is `140 - image_url.length` -- so you'll need to figure out what length twitter's image URLs are, and maybe add some padding for safety, depending on what you're doing.

There happens to be an API call that will give you the answer -- [`GET help/configuration`](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/help/configuration) will return a bunch of parameters, one of which is `characters_reserved_per_media` -- I assume if you subtract that amount from 140, you'll get the maximum number of characters you can use.

Comment: Ya.The same behavior is observed in web.When we attach a pic the char count reduces to 119.Thanks for the answer @muffinista